# Hibernate exception 'could not resolve property' when doing a query with Criteria and Restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I have a OneToMany relation in hibernate defined like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group extends BaseModel {// BaseModel defines id as @Id and @GeneratedValue

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private List<User> users;

    // other fields, getters and setters omitted 
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseModel {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;

    // other fields, getters and setters omitted 
}
```

Column `group_id` is in the users table.
Calling methods `Group.getUsers()` and `User.getGroup()` work fine. But I also need to do a query after the column `group_id`:

```
Criteria criteria = Activator.getDefault().getSQLSession().createCriteria(User.class);
Criterion c = Restrictions.eq("group_id", 1); // an id of a group
criteria.add(c);
```

The `Criterion` object is created in a method, and it can be for other *one-to-many* tables or can contain other columns, so I can't use method `getUsers()`.

Unfortunatelly, the code above gives the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: group_id of: com.example.User
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1482)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:62)
    and so on ...
```

What could be the problem?

---

**Edit:**

After the change that *user759837* suggested (`Criterion c = Restrictions.eq("group", 1);`), when I call `criteria.list()`, I get this error message: `could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.example.Group.id`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.example.BaseModel.id to java.lang.Long
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3875)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3583)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:130)
    ...
```

The BaseModel class is

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I tried with `long id` too, but it's the same error.

---

**Edit 2:**

After a lot of digging, it looks that the `Criterion` object should receive a group object as parameter, not an id: `Restrictions.eq("group", {A_GROUP_OBJECT});`

Could it be possible that I send there an id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
Criterion c = Restrictions.eq("group.id", 1); // an id of a group
```

Comment: +1 It helped me too, but why does it behave like that? I'm a hibernate newbie, and looking into the documentation gives me an impression that learning all the magic would take years.

Comment: i dont know why, but it helps =)

Answer (score 4):

your column is **group_id** and you should use the property which is **group**
...
Criterion c = Restrictions.eq("**group**", 1); // an id of a group
...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using oracle as your DB, the reason might be that group_id is a keyword in it.Change the name to something else and try.

Comment: No, it's not oracle, and the real column name isn't even `group_id`. I changed it so it was clearer.